# jquery not working in phonegap android

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

i have this simple app , that works fine in a browser , but when building it using phonegap it's just shows a simple html page, means that jquery not working ,

in my page i call the jquery mobile.min.css ,jquery.min.js than this script :

```
$(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function (event, data) {  
$.mobile.pageData = (data && data.options && data.options.pageData)
      ? data.options.pageData
      : null;
});
$(document).ready( function (event) {

  compSearch('');
  $("#searchbtn").click(function () {
    var sText = $("#searchtxt").val();        
    $("#search").dialog("close");
    compSearch(sText)
  });
 }); 
function compSearch(searchString) {
  var theUrl = serverName + "MobileService.asmx/getOrgPage";
  var orgId = qString("org");      

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: theUrl,
    data: '{"OrgId":' + orgId +
    ',"SearchString":"' + searchString +
    '"}',
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
      var s = msg.d[0];

      $("#header").html(s).trigger("create");

      $("#footer").html(msg.d[3]).trigger("create");          
      $("#contentHeading").html(msg.d[1]);          
      $("#content").html(msg.d[2]).find("ul").listview();

      $("#newscontent").html(msg.d[4]);

    },
    error: function (msg) {
      alert('error ' + msg.d[0]);
    }
  });

 } 

 $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#indivnews', function (event, data) {

  if ($.mobile.pageData && $.mobile.pageData.np) {


    var orgId = qString("org");

    var itemId = $.mobile.pageData.np;
    var theUrl = serverName + "MobileService.asmx/getNewsPage";
    var clubName = "";
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: theUrl,
      data: '{"orgId":' + orgId +
      ',"compId":' + 0 +
      ',"itemId":' + itemId +
      ',"clubName":"' + clubName +
      '"}',
      contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (msg) {
        var s = msg.d[0];

        $("#indivcontent").html(msg.d[4]);

      },
      error: function (msg) {
        alert('error ' + msg.d[0]);
      }
    });
     }
   });
```

than the jquery mobile.min.js

like i said it's works fine in a browser,please if you have and idea to solve it 
thank you.

Comment: are you initializing: jquery mobile.min.js ?

Comment: i didn't understand , i call the file :   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: all the jquery files are called from the source and they work fine on the browser .

Comment: This is your first mistake, when combining jQuery Mobile and Phonegap you should ALWAYS use local js/css files, never initialize them from remote source in this case. Phonegap and jQuery Mobile is already slow combination, now think what will happen when you start your app and you need to wait for files to initialize from remote source. Another thing, what if, for some reason, remote source id not available? You app will fail.

Comment: Plus have you gave your Phonegap android app permission to access internet?

Comment: @neustrebee Based on your comment, looks like you're missing `http://` in front of `code.jquery.com...`

Comment: @Gajotres i'll make them local and let you know

Comment: how can i add permission to access internet in the config.xml ? i have just set : access origin="*" , do i need to add someting else ?

Comment: hi @Gajotres i did what u'v said , the same issue .

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you are loading the html page before PQ and JQM are properly initialized. I use the following in my project to ensure the framework is loaded correctly:

```
 var deviceReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();
 var jqmReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();
 document.addEventListener("deviceReady", deviceReady, false);
function deviceReady() {
            deviceReadyDeferred.resolve();
        }

        $(document).one("pageinit", function () {
            jqmReadyDeferred.resolve();
        });
 $.when(deviceReadyDeferred, jqmReadyDeferred).then(frameworksLoaded);

        function frameworksLoaded() {
     $.support.cors = true;
     $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
     jQm.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
     console.log('PG & JQM ready');
    }

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width =device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<title>Test</title>
<link href="Example.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../www/Content/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../www/Content/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../www/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Reference to Deferred and Jquery Promises:

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/

Comment: hi @Chad i also decalred the page after the code below , and stay the same problem